# Python - Getting week number from date and viceversa not corresponding

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following problem: from a given date I need to find the week number of that year and then find the start day and end day of that week.

```
day1= datetime.datetime(2015,9,28)
day2= datetime.datetime(2017,12,18)
```

finding the week works fine:

```
day1.isocalendar()
day2.isocalendar()
```

returns

```
(2015, 40, 1)
(2017, 51, 1)
```

Which also corresponds with some standard calendars:
http://whatweekisit.org/calendar-2015.html

Then I defined the following function:

```
def week_start_end(year,week):
    '''Given year and week, returns the start and end day of the week
as datetime object'''
    w = "%s-W%s"%(year,week)
    s = datetime.datetime.strptime(w + '-1', "%Y-W%W-%w")#monday
    e= datetime.datetime.strptime(w + '-0', "%Y-W%W-%w")#sunday
    return (s,e)
```

when I call it with the year and week as arguments:

```
week_start_end(2015,40)
week_start_end(2017,51)
```

returns the following:

```
(datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 11, 0, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 18, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 24, 0, 0))
```

As you can see, it is working well for the 2nd date, but not for the first. Trying several instances, I have realised that this function always returns one week later than it should for 2015, but gets it right for 2016 and 2017.

I could not find my way through it. Can you help me please?

Comment: Welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)!

Comment: Thanks, I actually had a lot of help from it already, but this time I really had to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the library [isoweek](https://pypi.org/project/isoweek/)

```
from isoweek import Week

def week_start_end(year, week):
    '''Given year and week, returns the start and end day of the week
as datetime object'''
    w = Week(year, week)
    s = w.monday()
    e = w.sunday()
    return (s,e)
```

And finally

```
>>> week_start_end(2015, 40)
(datetime.date(2015, 9, 28), datetime.date(2015, 10, 4))
>>> week_start_end(2017, 51)
(datetime.date(2017, 12, 18), datetime.date(2017, 12, 24))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My program works fine now. I guess there are a few things I don´t know yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Different week numbering conventions. The week number you get with %W is not the same as the ISO week number. I believe that you can get ISO week numbers with %V, but I have not tried it and it seems to be platform dependent.